Crawlspace encapsulatation options
I'm being quoted from multiple companies, wonder what is the best. The house is 100 years old and you can basically stand in crawl space. AC and hot water heater is down there. Here are my options for the walls:

spray foam w/10mil vapor floor
Foam board w/12mil vap floor
Insul-barrier roll (blanket) 16mil floor
What seems to be the best option. Spray seems the best but people say it's a lot to remove if you need it gone.

